# Error in Cassandra while exporting data

Tags: cassandra, timeout, cassandra-2.0, datastax, cqlsh

I have a column family (eventData) in `cassandra` keyspace. Which has the following definition :

```
CREATE TABLE eventData (
  col1 text,    
  col2 text,    
  col3 text,
  col4 int,
  col5 int,
  col6 int,
  col7 timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY (col7, col1, col2)
);
```

I have scheduled on `cron job` which export the data from `cassandra` in a text file and it is defined like this :

```
dd=$(date --date yesterday "+%Y-%m-%d")
echo "select * FROM keyspacename.eventData where col7 = '$dd' ;" | /home/cassuser/Desktop/cassandra212/bin/cqlsh > /home/cassuser/Desktop/cassandra212/Dump/output-$dd.txt
```

So, above statement give the following error every day when `cron job` runs. But i run the same query from `cqlsh` manually it export the data without any error. Can anyone tell me the reason for this?

**Error :**

```
<stdin>:2:errors={}, last_host=localhost
```

I read many post on SO, most them say this error might be because of read_timeout. But my question is why can't i get the same error while running the same query from `cqlsh` manually.

Comment: Where is "dd" defined? many errors in cron happen because it does not have the same paths, environment variables, aliases, etc than the user. Also, have a look here for common cron problems: [Cron problem wiki](http://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work).

Comment: Well, I am surprised you couldn't find WHERE dd is defined. Kindly look again and regarding the paths, environment and alias. I have one more column family from which i export the data. That works fine. So, there is no problem with that.

Comment: It is common to define similars commands in a bash_aliases file (which me thinks is not seen by cron) and that's why I asked. I suggest reviewing the link I posted in the previous comment for a wiki of the most commont problems using cron.